# How do I call this array?

Tags: java, methods, call

I'm currently working on this school project and I can't figure out how to call this method mainly because I don't even know what to search for. However I do believe that I am suppose to create an object and reference that? I'm also calling from another method and not my main.

```
    public String[] unique(String[] words) {
        //more code
    return resizeStringArray(uniqueWords,nUnique);
}
```

Comment: So your calling this method from another method. Do both methods exist in the same class?

Comment: @BryanHerrera yes it does

Comment: calling it should be as simple as unique([some array of strings])

Comment: then since youre expecting a string array, you'll need to have a string array variable ready to accept the return value.

Comment: @BryanHerrera oh my gosh thank you so much, I'm sick right now and can't think for a minute about what I'm doing.

Comment: np dude. Hope you get better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you could achieve.

1. create an object/instance and call the method
2. declare method as static and call with Class name

Let's see here 
Approach 1

```
Class SomeClass {
 public String[] unique(String[] words) {
        //more code
    return resizeStringArray(uniqueWords,nUnique);
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     SomeClass classInstance = new SomeClass();
     //calling method
     classInstance.unique(words);
 }
}
```

Approach 2

```
Class SomeClass {
 public static String[] unique(String[] words) {
        //more code
    return resizeStringArray(uniqueWords,nUnique);
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     // Use only Classname and "."
     SomeClass.unique(words);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you must have the method in a class declaration, and you say it's not in the same class as your `main` method, so lets call it `AnotherClass`. Then your method looks like this:

```
public class AnotherClass(){
  //initialization stuff here

  public String[] unique(String[] words) {
      //more code
  return resizeStringArray(uniqueWords,nUnique);
  }
}
```

then, somewhere you have instantiated an object of type `AnotherClass`, so you can call it with dot notation, something like

```
AnotherClass myinstance = new AnotherClass;
```

and then

```
someUniqueWords[] = myinstance.unique(String[] somewords)
```

If you don't have an instantiation then you can just call the method via

```
someUniqueWords[] = unique(String[] somewords)
```